# excluding certain topics

Tags: support

On superuser.com I have a whole load of excluded tags added to my list. The only problem is that questions with these tags still appear when I go into the unanswered list. They appear greyed out and occupy the majority of what I see.

Is there any way to not see them. Knowing the good people on stackoverflow there probably is an option somewhere.

It seems a bit pointless displaying them as they're topics I know nothing about - which is why they're in my exclude list in the first place. I've tried searching the forums but nothing has shown up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to your profile page and under the `info` and `prefs` tabs, there should be a checkbox `hide ignored tags`.  Make sure you check it.

[image]

Comment: +1 for freehand circle?

Comment: perfect, thanks. Hadn't ever entered these other tabs. In fact I hadn't even noticed they were tabs.